# Plot sine wave (degrees)

Tags: python, trigonometry, degrees

We're supposed to plot the sine wave with  the help of Matplotlib but in degrees.

First we're supposed to get every sin(x) from 0-360 degrees, every ten degrees.

I'm a beginner, would really appreciate the help.

```
def getsin():
    for i in range(0,361,10):
        y=math.sin(math.radians(i))
        sinvalue.append(round(y,3)
sinvalue=[]
getsin()


x=np.linspace(0,360,37)
plot.plot(x,sinvalue)
plot.xlabel("x, degrees")
plot.ylabel("sin(x)")
plot.show()
```

Comment: In your code example you don't need to define a function. Just remove that line and declare `sinvalue` before. The rest seems perfectly fine to me

Comment: lol ok that solved the problem, thanks! could you explain to me why it made a diffrenece to not define a function? because the output in sinvalue should be the same with or without function..

Comment: Why did you edit half of your question away? You chopped it off in the middle of a word and removed all code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost OK (you missed a closing parenthesis on line `sinvalue.append(round(y,3)`), but it can be perfected.

E.g., it's usually considered bad practice updating a global variable (I mean `sinvalue`) from inside a function... I don't say that it should never be done, I say that it should be avoided as far as possible.

A more common pattern is to have the function to return a value...

```
def getsin():
    sines = []
    for i in range(0,361,10):
        y=math.sin(math.radians(i))
        sines.append(round(y,3))
    return sines
```

Why I say this is better?  Compare

```
sinvalue=[]
getsin()
```

with

```
sinvalue = getsin()
```

At least in my opinion, the second version is *waaay* better because it makes clear what is happening, now `sinvalue` is clearly the result of getting the sines...